# vb.net How to sort data in listview?

Tags: vb.net

How to sort data in a listview?
I want to sort data text files in a listview box.
But my code only reads the file, not sorting data.

first data

```
2011-03-09 11:03:02
2011-03-09 10:03:12
2011-03-09 12:03:07
2011-03-09 07:04:02
2011-03-09 01:45:04
2011-03-09 11:56:02
2011-03-09 11:46:03
2011-03-09 11:03:42
2011-03-09 01:33:02
2011-03-09 12:23:05
2011-03-09 08:13:12
2011-03-09 09:03:01
2011-05-05 15:05:42
2011-05-05 01:33:12
2011-05-05 12:23:15
2011-05-05 03:13:22
2011-05-05 04:03:31
```

....................
    (200 file)
I want

```
2011-03-09 01:33:02
2011-03-09 01:45:04
2011-03-09 07:04:02
2011-03-09 08:13:12
2011-03-09 09:03:01
2011-03-09 10:03:12
2011-03-09 11:03:42
2011-03-09 11:46:03
2011-03-09 11:56:02
2011-03-09 12:03:07
2011-03-09 12:23:05
2011-05-05 01:33:12
2011-05-05 03:13:22
2011-05-05 04:03:31
2011-05-05 12:23:15
2011-05-05 15:05:42
...........
```

Comment: Please give some more information about what code you tried, what technologies you use, and what the specific problem ist.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is not a free code writing service

Answer (score 0):

If you have loaded these in to an array this can be done very easily:

```
Array.Sort(myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd use e.g. a `ListBox` instead of `ListView` for your needs. Please note the Array.Sort method like shown in the code below is used before adding the items. This should work for a ListView too.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
    Dim arrPointList() As String

    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    Try
      '--- read DateTime as text to array ----------
      arrPointList = File.ReadAllLines("D:\file-date-time-values.txt")
      '--- sort array -----
      Array.Sort(arrPointList)
      '--- Dim sLine As String = Join(arrPointList, ",")
    Catch ex As Exception
      '--- log message ----------
      MessageBox.Show("Check if file exists!", "Reading error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
      Exit Sub
    End Try

    For Each myLine In arrPointList
      ListBox1.Items.Add(myLine)
    Next
  End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]